# cap deploy error - Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, bundler

I am trying to deploy my application  (`cap deploy:cold`) and all goes smooth until:

```
Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the sources
```

Now, I've seen other posts like this, but they all point to a Passenger problem, and in my case I have nginx on the server (Ubuntu Server 12.04) instead.

I am relatively new to Rails so I could be missing a basic thing here, but I do know that i18n is installed locally (OS X Mountain Lion), 'bundle show i18n' gives me:

```
/Users/myhomedirectory/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/i18n-0.6.4
```

Is the problem on my server? How do I approach this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Below the Capistrano Recipe

```
require "rvm/capistrano"

server 'myserverip', :web, :app, :db, primary: true

set :application, "siac"
set :user, "deployer"
set :deploy_to, "/home/#{user}/apps/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :use_sudo, false

set :rvm_type, :system

set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "mygitdir"
set :branch, "master"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

namespace :deploy do
  %w[start stop restart].each do |command|
    desc "#{command} unicorn server"
    task command, roles: :app, except: {no_release: true} do
      run "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application} #{command}"
    end
  end

  task :setup_config, roles: :app do
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/#{application}"
    sudo "ln -nfs #{current_path}/config/unicorn_init.sh /etc/init.d/unicorn_#{application}"
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
    put File.read("config/database.yml.tpl"), "#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"
    puts "Now edit the config files in #{shared_path}."
  end
  after "deploy:setup", "deploy:setup_config"

  task :symlink_config, roles: :app do
    run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/config/database.yml #{release_path}/config/database.yml"
  end
  after "deploy:finalize_update", "deploy:symlink_config"

  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision, roles: :web do
    unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
      puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
      puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
      exit
    end
  end
  before "deploy", "deploy:check_revision"
end
```

and the stacktrace:

```
  * executing "cd -- /home/deployer/apps/siac/releases/20130319035235 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp -- /home/deployer/apps/siac/shared/assets/manifest.yml /home/deployer/apps/siac/releases/20130319035235/assets_manifest.yml"
    servers: ["myserverip"]
    [myserverip] executing command
 ** [out :: myserverip] Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the sources
 ** [out :: myserverip] Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
    command finished in 905ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /home/deployer/apps/siac/releases/20130319035235; true"
    servers: ["myserverip"]
    [myserverip] executing command
    command finished in 627ms
failed: "rvm_path=/usr/local/rvm /usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'cd -- /home/deployer/apps/siac/releases/20130319035235 && rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile && cp -- /home/deployer/apps/siac/shared/assets/manifest.yml /home/deployer/apps/siac/releases/20130319035235/assets_manifest.yml'" on myserverip
```

Comment: Could you post your your `cap deploy:cold` script, and the stacktrace you get when deploying?

Comment: as it said you need to run `bundle install` in server.

Comment: Right, but where, what path? Capistrano deleted the folder with the app under "releases" in the roll back so there is not place with my code nor the Gemfile for me to run bundle install

Comment: Try `cap setup` then you can use `cap shell` to go in and install the i18n gem...

Comment: Thank you guys, after doing some tests with `cap shell` and `cap invoke COMMAND=`,  I ended up cleaning up the capistrano recipe, fixing some sym links on the server side and I got it to work. Thanks to all!

Comment: Be sure to answer your own question.  :)

Comment: @GastonConcilio - If you're game to recap the solution as your own answer, I'll delete my answer. (See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments for elaboration of why this is helpful.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying the answer from the comments in order to remove this question from the "Unanswered" filter:

> Thank you guys, after doing some tests with **cap shell** and **cap
>   invoke COMMAND=**, I ended up cleaning up the capistrano recipe, fixing
>   some sym links on the server side and I got it to work. Thanks to all!

~ answer per [Gaston Concilio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036654/gaston-concilio)